# use of grep commands in unix

Tags: unix

I have a file and i want to sort it according to a word and to remove the special characters.
The grep command is used to search for the characters

```
-b Display the block number at the beginning of each line. 
-c Display the number of matched lines. 
-h Display the matched lines, but do not display the filenames. 
-i Ignore case sensitivity. 
-l Display the filenames, but do not display the matched lines. 
-n Display the matched lines and their line numbers. 
-s Silent mode. 
-v Display all lines that do NOT match. 
-w Match whole word
```

but 
How to use the grep command to do the `file sort` and `remove the special character` and number.

Comment: I think this is a long way from being a comprehensible question, not to mention that it's almost certainly off-topic for SO.

Comment: sort command will sort it and pipe it to the grep or sed and remove your char with regexp

Comment: define `sort it according to a word` and `the special characters`

Answer (score 2):

grep searches inside all the files to find matching text. It doesn't really sort and it doesn't really chop and change output. What you want is probably to use the sort command

```
sort <filename>
```

and the output sent to either the awk command or the sed command, which are common tools for manipulating text.

```
sort <filename> | sed 's/REPLACE/NEW_TEXT/g'
```

something like above I'd imagine.

Answer (score 2):

The following command would do it.

```
 sort FILE  | tr -d 'LIST OF SPECIAL CHARS' > NEW_FILE
```